# How many ways can N elements be partitioned into subsets of size K?

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

Let's have $2$ numbers, $N$ and $K$, where $K$ divides $N$. The number of $K$-combinations from a given set $S$ of $N$ elements is a well-known formula. Let's concatenate $N/K$ groups (resulting in $N$ elements) such that the resulting set is $N$. How many possibilities are there, i.e. what's the formula?

For instance:
$N=4$, and $K=2$, gives $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{1,4\}$, $\{2,3\}$, $\{2,4\}$, $\{3,4\}$

The $3$ possibilities are:

$\{1,2\}$, $\{3,4\}$
$\{1,3\}$, $\{2,4\}$
$\{1,4\}$, $\{2,3\}$

I generated these combinations and I think the number goes like this:

$$
\begin{align}
(4, 2)&: 3 \\
(6, 3)&: 10 \\
(6, 2)&: 15 \\
(10, 5)&: 126 \\
(9, 3)&: 280 \\
(10, 2)&: 945 \\
(14, 7)&: 1716 \\ 
(12, 4)&: 5775 \\ 
(15, 5)&: 126126 \\
(15, 3)&: 1401400
\end{align}
$$

Apparently, the result always divides with $(N-1)$.

Comment: The order of the groups doesn't matter, i.e. {3,4},{1,2} = {1,2},{3,4}, {2,4},{1,3} = {1,3},{2,4}, etc.

Comment: In what context did you encounter this problem? Did you try anything / do you have any thoughts on a solution?

Comment: The context for those interested: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105154/n-choose-k-k-n-k-2n-etc-recursion-within-recursion/21148261#21148261)

Comment: Cool, I was just wondering myself about the problem of generating these partitions; have posted an answer there on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to count the number of [set partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Partition_of_a_set&oldid=582219511) of a set of $n$ elments, into $n/k$ parts each of size $k$.
(It is assumed that $k$ divides $n$.)

**Method 1.**

We can generate such a partition by writing down the $n$ elements in a sequence, and then declaring that the first $k$ elements are the first part, the next $k$ elements are the second part, and so on. There are $n!$ ways of writing $n$ elements in a sequence, but each partition is generated multiple times: for each of the $n/k$ parts, there are $k!$ orderings of the $k$ elements in that part that would lead to the same partition, as you don't care about the order within each part. Further, there are $(n/k)!$ orderings of the parts themselves, for the same partition.

The number of partitions is therefore:
$$\frac{n!}{(k!)^{n/k} (n/k)!}$$

**Method 2.**

You can choose the elements of the first part in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways, then choose the elements of the second part as $k$ out of the remaining $n-k$ in $\binom{n-k}{k}$ ways, and so on. But as different orderings of the $(n/k)$ parts don't change the partition, the number of partitions is

$$\frac{\binom{n\vphantom{k}}{k}\binom{n-k}{k}\cdots\binom{k}{k}}{(n/k)!} = \frac{n!}{(k!)^{n/k}(n/k)!}$$ 
as before.

You can verify that this accords with all your cases. For instance, for $n=15$ and $k=5$, you get $\frac{15!}{5!^3 3!} = 126126$. These numbers are tabulated in [OEIS A060540](http://oeis.org/A060540), and no simpler formula is listed.

Comment: It also validates for `(15, 3) = 1401400`, just added. I'll have more time the next days.

Comment: The prove seems correct and the formula is valid for the given numbers, but I still wait for a few days before accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrongly interpreting your question (forgive me if this is the case). But based on certain phrases (i.e., "number of $k$-combinations of a given set" and "The order of the groups doesn't matter [from comments]) in addition to the numbers you put forth in your question, it seems to me that you are looking for the formula for:

The number of ways to **choose** $k$ items at a time from a set of $n$ items.

It turns out that this idea of combinatorics has very deep and interesting applications to nearly every branch of mathematics. The terminology for the number you seek is called a **Binomial Coefficient** and the notation for the statement above is $$ \binom{n}{k} = \text{number of ways to choose $k$ items from a set of $n$ items}$$ That is why the notation $\binom{n}{k}$ is also pronounced "$n$-choose-$k$". There are other notations including $C(n,k$), $C_k^n$, $_nC_k$, $C^k_n$, but I will continue to use the notation $\binom{n}{k}$ in this answer. For those of you wondering how to type it in a math-environment like TeX,LaTeX,etc. (because eventually I'm sure you will encounter the occasion to use the notation in an answer - that's how prolific binomial coefficients are), you want to use $\$\text{\binom{n}{k}}$\$.

There are many different formulas for binomial coefficients and it is a shame that I can't list them all. However, before we jump into some formulas, it is worth our time to introduce some useful notation is that presented by the [Factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial). Incidentally, the number of ways to *arrange* (order matters) $k$ objects from a set of $n$ objects is related to [Permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) which uses the factorial extensively.

Define $n! = \prod\limits_{k=1}^n k = 1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots(n-1)\cdot n$. The convention for "vacuous products" lets us define $0!=1$ but this can also be verified using the definition of the [Gamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) where the notion of a factorial can be extended to all real numbers (except negative integers). Since $n! = n\cdot(n-1)\cdots2\cdot1$, we can condense this into $n!=n(n-1)!$ and immediately see a recursive relation defined by the factorial. Some values that are worth memorizing include: $$0!=1 (\text{by defintion})\\ 1!=1 \\ 2!=2=2*1 \\ 3!=6=3*2*1 \\ 4!=24=4*3*2*1 \\ 5!=120=5*4*3*2*1$$.

Back to combinations, one of the most fundamental formulas for a binomial coefficient is:

$$ \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)(n-k)!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k(k-1)\cdots(1)} \\ \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n^{\underline{k}}}{k!} = \prod\limits_{j=1}^{k} \frac{n+1-j}{j} \quad \text{integer $k \geq 0$}$$

In particular, it is straightforward to verify that
$$\binom{n}{0} = \binom{n}{n} = 1 \qquad \binom{n}{1} = n \qquad \binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Also, the following identity is one reason why high symmetry exists in [Pascal's Triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle):

$$ \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$$

---

So now you have your formula(s) for $\binom{n}{k}$ and a little crash course on factorials. I have computed the same numbers below that you input originally and computed there corresponding [binomial coffecients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

$$\binom{4}{2} = 6, \quad \binom{6}{3} = 20, \quad \binom{6}{2} = 15, \\
\binom{10}{5} = 252, \quad \binom{9}{3} = 84, \quad \binom{10}{2} = 45, \\
\binom{14}{7} = 3432, \quad \binom{12}{4} = 495, \quad \binom{15}{5} = 3003
$$
Some of your numbers are either correct or halved (if combinations are what you're after). Given the definitions above, it wouldn't be hard to write a new program with inputs $n$ and $k$ to output $\binom{n}{k}$.

Here's an answer for your bounty message:
"...I'm not a mathematician. Are they on this site?"

Yes. Yes we are.

Comment: I don't have the time right now, but the formula from the answer of ShreevatsaR works for the next 3 tests: (15,5), (15,3), (10,2).

Comment: Thank you for the generous answer, but I'm not looking for the k-combinations in n, but for the  sequences of such combinations that cover the entire set (given that k divides n).
For exemple, for (6,3):
{1 2 3} {4 5 6},
{1 2 4} {3 5 6},
{1 2 5} {3 4 6},
{1 2 6} {3 4 5},
{1 3 4} {2 5 6},
{1 3 5} {2 4 6},
{1 3 6} {2 4 5},
{1 4 5} {2 3 6},
{1 4 6} {2 3 5},
{1 5 6} {2 3 4}

(10 solutions)