# Partitions with pairwise small intersection

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

Let $n$ and $k$ be positive integers, such that $k$ is a divisor of $n$. I am interested in creating a sequence of partitions of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, like the one below. The rules are this:

- Each row is a partition of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ into $n/k$ disjoint sets, each with size $k$.
- For any two subsets $S$ and $T$ appearing in the list of partitions, $S$ and $T$ have at most one element in common.

Example with $n=12$ and $k=3$. You can make a list of three partitions:

$$\{\{1,2,3\},\{4,5,6\},\{7,8,9\},\{10,11,12\}\},\\
\{\{1,4,7\},\{2,5,10\},\{3,8,11\},\{6,9,12\}\},\\
\{\{1,5,8\},\{2,4,12\},\{3,9,10\},\{6,7,11\}\}$$

This is valid because, for example, $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{1,4,7\}$ have at most one element in common, and the same for $\{4,5,6\}$ and $\{1,5,8\}$, and for every other way to choose two subsets from this list of partitions.

The total number of possible partitions is equal to $\frac{n!}{(k!)^{n/k}\cdot (n/k)!}$, but the size of the largest list will be much smaller than this due to the at-most-one condition.

> **Question:** What is known about the length largest possible list of partitions satisfying these conditions?

Comment: The case where $k=3$ is discussed pretty much completely in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4509843/efficient-way-to-rotate-through-partitions-with-subsets-of-size-three/). You should not expect a simple formula, and this is in fact likely to be an open problem in general.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you for editing, it's much better now, and thank you for the answer. So if I want the case $\{20,4\}$ or $\{24,8\}$, I need to brute force?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Furthermore with the formula you wrote for the possible partitions for the case $n=12, k=3$, the result is $15400$, but it should be $92400$. What's wrong?

Comment: $92400$ is wrong. My formula is correct, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640558/how-many-ways-can-n-elements-be-partitioned-into-subsets-of-size-k

Comment: @MikeEarnest Ok, yes, there was an error, thank you. So,  no simple formula for other cases, do you have any reference?

Comment: Um {24, 8} is trivial, no? Each row will have 3 sets in it. So any two rows, the 24 elements are split up into 9 intersections, so some intersection must be of size at least 3. Since this isn't allowed, you can only have one row.

Comment: You may want to examine the literature on [Kirkman's Schoolgirl Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem), Steiner triple sets, and block design in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(n,k)$ be number of interest, the size largest list of partitions for a given $n$ and $k$. Here is what I could figure out about $P(n,k)$.

- We have the upper bound
  $
  P(n,k)\le \frac{n-1}{k-1},
  $
  which follows because in each partition, $1$ needs to be grouped with $k-1$ new numbers, and there are only $n-1$ other numbers.
- If $k> \sqrt n$, then $P(n,k)=1$.  If $k$ numbers are together in one partition, then those $k$ numbers all need to be in different parts in the next partition. Since there are $n/k$ parts, this means we need $n/k\ge k$ in order to have two or more partitions.
- If $k^2<n$, and $n/k$ is a prime power, then $P(n,k)\ge \frac{n}k$.
   The strategy is to construct $k$ mutually orthogonal Lain squares using the finite field construction. Specifically, choose binary operations $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ on the set $F:=\{0,\dots,n/k-1\}$ such that $(F,\oplus,\otimes)$ is a finite field, where $0$ is the zero element. Then, construct $k$ Latin squares $L^1,\dots,L^k$, each of order $n/k$, via the formula $$L^m_{i,j}=m\otimes i\oplus j \qquad i,j\in F,m\in \{1,\dots,k\}$$Then, concatenate these together to get an $(n/k)\times n$ matrix $[L^1\mid L^2\mid \dots \mid L^k]$. Each row of this matrix represents a partition of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, where for each $i\in \{1,\dots,n/k\}$, the $i^\text{th}$ part consists of the column indices of the entries containing $i$. 
  **Example:** Using this strategy, we can improve on your result for $n=12,k=3$. The finite field construction produces these three squares:

  ```
  1 2 3 4  1 2 3 4  1 2 3 4
  2 1 4 3  4 3 2 1  3 4 1 2
  3 4 1 2  2 1 4 3  4 3 2 1 
  4 3 2 1  3 4 1 2  2 1 4 3
  ```

  Translating this into a list of four partitions, the result is
  $$
  \begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
  1,5,9&2,6,10& 3,7,11&4,8,12\\
  2,8,11&1,7,12& 4,6,9&3,5,10\\
  3,6,12&4,5,11& 1,8,10&2,7,9\\
  4,7,10&3,8,9& 2,5,12&1,6,11
  \end{array}
  $$
- If $k^2=n$, and there exist $\ell-2$ mutually orthogonal Latin squares (MOLS), then $P(n,k)\ge \ell$. In particular, if $k$ is a prime power, then $P(n,k)=k+1$.
  The strategy is to convert the MOLS into an orthogonal array, $OA(\ell, k)$, following the instructions in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_orthogonal_Latin_squares#Orthogonal_array). The result is a $k^2\times \ell$ matrix. Each column of that matrix can be turned into a partition, using the same strategy as in the last section, so we get $\ell$ partitions which satisfy the conditions.
- $P(2n,2)=2n-1$, via a [Round robin tournament schedule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm).
- $P(6n+3,3)=3n+1$, via a [Kirkman Triple System](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KirkmanTripleSystem.html).
- $P(n,k)$ attains its optimal value of $\frac{n-1}{k-1}$ if and only if a resolvable Steiner system $S(2,k,n)$ exists. 
   A Steiner system, $S(t,k,n)$, is a collection of blocks, where each block a size-$k$ subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$,  such that every size-$t$ subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ is contained in exactly one block. This is called *resolvable* if the blocks can be partitioned into *parallel classes*, where each parallel class is set of pairwise disjoint blocks whose union is $\{1,\dots,n\}$. This is essentially a tautology, but it gives a connection with existing research.

Comment: Thank you! That way is easy to find the permutations for $ n=20, k=4$ are $5$. Just one last question: is easy to see that there is no partition with $n=24, k=8$, but if I ask for partitions with at max 2 times the presence of one couple of values, can I use the same method to find those partitions? I tried with $ (24, 8) $, using the first $4 $ raws of the first $ 3 $ MOLS $ (8) $ [I found them in Handbook of combinatorial designs], as a result I get https://pastebin.com/35ZEw8it and as you can see there are values showing up $3$ times [like $(1,11)$ or $(7,8)$]. How to fix that?

Comment: @user967210 You are doing the construction wrong. When you apply my construction to the first four rows of three $8\times 8$ MOLS, you should get partitions into eight parts of size three, but you have three parts of size $8$. For example, the first partition would be $1, 9, 17\mid  2, 10, 18\mid 3, 11, 19\mid 4, 12, 20\mid 5, 13, 21\mid 6, 14, 22,\mid 7, 15, 23\mid 8, 16, 24 $. You cannot just arbitrarily change the groupings and expect things to work out. I think allowing two occurrences of each pair requires a different strategy. I suggest making a separate post to ask on MSE.

Comment: @user967210 By the way, I corrected my answer to remove a mistake. You cannot just use _any_ MOLS like I original wrote, you need to specifically use the finite field construction.